# Empantanado ,join en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lo he intentado de todas formas pero no logro traer los datos que necesito (llegue al limite de mi ignorancia).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso necesito que la consulta me devuelva todos los socios que sean activos y que no tengan un registro en la tabla de pagos de una determinada fecha.

Agradecido por una ayuda.

Comment: SELECT campo_Que_quiero_mostrar1, campo_Que_quiero_mostrar2 FROM Tabla1 INNER JOIN Tabla2 on Tabla1.id = Tabla2.id;

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y podrias mostrar lo que intentaste? asi trabajamos sobre eso...

Comment: Prueba lo siguiente: `SELECT Socios.Nombre, Socios.Apellido, Pagos.FechaPago FROM Socios INNER JOIN Pagos on Socios.id = Pagos.Socioid WHERE Socio.Activo=true;` si el campo Activo de tu tabla socio es distinto a un boolean entonces debes agregar la instruccion alli en el WHERE.

Comment: Lo he intentado de esa forma pero no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy buenas!

Para que el resultado tenga los records de socios por su estatus y las fechas de pago, hay que hacer un **left outer join**, que busca los records de la tabla transaccional según una tabla clave (a la izquierda).

Explico: Si consideremos que hay socios que no están involucrados en transacciones de pagos y hay días en los cuales un socio no realizó pagos, éstos récords tienen que ser filtrados. De lo contrario, si hago un **inner join** sencillo, los records de socio tambien no estarán presentes en el resultado.

Por eso, hago un join entre la tabla principal de socio y una consulta (subquery) a la tabla de pago considerando la cantidad de records agrupados por SocioId filtrados por fecha.

Mira como lo hice en el código SQL.

```
declare @DeterminadaFecha datetime

-- elije una fecha
--set @DeterminadaFecha = ''

select * 
from socios s 
left join (select SocioId,count(*) NumRegistros
            from Pagos 
            where FechaPago=@DeterminadaFecha 
            group by SocioId) p on s.Id=p.SocioId
where s.Activo=1 and (p.NumRegistros = 0 or p.NumRegistros is null)
```

El filtro de la clausa where para capturar los casos en que no hay ningún registro del socio en la tabla Pagos `(p.NumRegistros is null)` y los que hay pero no en la fecha determinada `(p.NumRegistros = 0)`.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias Fabio, funciono perfectamente, ahora la voy a desmenuzar para entenderla, no puedo marcar tu respuesta como útil porque no me deja, quizás porque tengo poco puntaje no se, abrazo

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Gracias! Les pido disculpas, de hecho no tuvo tiempo de responder apropiadamente. Pero hace pronto agregué más información acerca de cómo lo resolví. Un abrazo

Answer (score 3):

Puesto que ya hay una respuesta, creo que será mejor si incluyo la mejor opción considerando el rendimiento. No es necesario traer todos los datos de la tabla de pagos, solo es necesario ver si existen datos que correspondan según el criterio.

Para eso, tenemos la función `EXISTS()` y la negación `NOT`. Esto puede validar de una forma más rápida la existencia sin tener que calcular un agregado. También omitirá los socios inactivos que tampoco hay necesidad de contar. Y por último, no agrega columnas innecesarias al resultado.

```
SELECT * 
FROM socios s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
                  FROM Pagos p
                  WHERE FechaPago = @DeterminadaFecha 
                  AND p.SocioId = s.Id)
AND s.Activo = 1;
```

Comment: Su código es mas simple pero llevado a la practica no funciona, el alias de la tabla Socios no muestra en el intellinsense los campos , y si coloco p.SocioId =  s.Id me lo subraya con Rojo no reconociendolo ,lo mismo que el último WHERE.

Comment: Perdón, tuve un par de errores al copiar y modificar el código. El último WHERE debía ser un AND puesto que ya tenemos el WHERE antes. El error del nombre de columna es porque no me fijé que el nombre cambiaba. Como recomendación, es una práctica poco apreciada el nombrar una columna solo como ID.

Comment: Tomaré en cuenta su sugerencia, obviamente queda mucho mas claro cuando se plantea la condición, agradezco su tiempo y conocimiento.